# Replace all occurrences of Ñ to N in string in shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to replace all occurrences of Ñ to N in a string.

So far I did this:

```
HOLA="HOLAÑÑÑA" 
echo $HOLA|sed -r 's/Ñ/N/g'
```

but I get `HOLAN` instead of `HOLANNNA`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ¿your example works here?

Comment: Your example works for me:
]# HOLA="HOLAÑÑÑA"
]# echo $HOLA|sed -r 's/Ñ/N/g'
HOLANNNA
Give some other information, are you in a script? Where are you storing the result?

Comment: There is no need of `-r` flag for `sed`. As pointed out by @Thomas8, your code doesn't replicate the issue you are describing.

Comment: Hmm, I my workstation it works as expected. This might be a Locale related problem in the server.

Comment: ¿export LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8?

Comment: Name your shell, your sed version, your Linux, your platform, .... there are zero details here!

Answer (score 5):

No need to use sed, just do this:

```
echo ${HOLA//Ñ/N}
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed. I'm getting the same result. I'll

Comment: That was an excellent reply. Thanks. I liked your reply.

Answer (score 1):

slight variation to replace all occurrences directly in the string, I like to use:

```
    HOLA="HOLAÑÑÑA" 
    echo $HOLA
    HOLA="${HOLA//Ñ/N}"
    echo $HOLA
```